# Setting up private nameservers

Tags: server, dns

I am wanting to setup private nameservers; 
like ns1.domain.com & ns2.domain.com

and I am wanting to make my ubuntu server to point these nameservers to this machine.
So now to manage DNS for a domain like somedomain.com I can point that domain to ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com

I have been looking into something like bind9; but I am not sure how I can get started with setting up private nameservers or is it something which I need to purchase from some where to register those as nameservers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a nameserver for use on a LAN and you can configure it to resolve names any way you like. But if you want computers on the Internet to be able to reach your machines by domain name then you will have to pay money to register that domain name with a domain name registrar.